Struggling to understand how a JK flip flop can behave contrary to understanding
I have tried to understand how the JK flip flop in the image below (U3B) is behaving, and I am at a loss.

For context, I've included related parts of the circuit. However, to avoid muddling my issue, I'm just trying to understand how the highlighted JK flip flop is behaving.
Note: This doesn't happen on every trigger of the JK flip flop. It is frequent enough to easily capture, but it is not every single time.
My understanding is there should be no way that the output of the flip flop could transition to a HI value unless the CLK signal has a leading edge.
Under that assumption, I cannot understand this oscilloscope output:

In this image, the yellow line is measuring the CLK signal, the cyan line is measuring the inverted CLK signal (see schematic image), and the darker blue line is measuring the output of the JK flip flop (pin 10, or DO_IRQ signal).
How is it that the CLK signal seems to clearly be transitioning from a high value (~4.92V on the scope) to a low value (~0V) and yet the output signal of the JK flip flop is changing from low to high?!
I read about "ones catching" from this answer, but I cannot convince myself that is the problem here. I also don't fully understand whether the noted issue in that answer applies.

The scope color description in the text does not match that on the drawing - which is correct?

The description looks correct upon re-reading. The cyan (lighter blue) is the inverted CLK signal, which is what is marked in the schematic as CLK with an overbar. The yellow line is the CLK signal, also marked in the schematic as the clock input on the JK. Finally, the darker blue line is noted as the JK output, just as it is marked in the schematic. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but it all looks correct to me.

Are you sure you measured Q and not Qbar? If Rbar goes low, it could produce a 1-0 transition on Q or a 0-1 on Qbar, not controlled by CLK. And a falling edge on CLK would be a rising edge on CLKbar, which could trigger U2A to change the signal driving Rbar.

From periblepsis's comment.  The inputs are J and /K (not-K) so if you tie them together, the FF acts as a D type.

@periblepsis this JK flip flop has the K input inverted (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd54hct109.pdf), so this should not act as a toggle but should operate like a D flip flop.

@ThePhoton I just double checked, and yes I am measuring the Q output. I know this is the case because I have header pins on a few of the signals, and my dark blue probe is definitely on the header pin connected to the Q output of the flip flop. There is no header pin available for the Qbar output.

@Burglups I have several pairs of decoupling capacitors (1uF and 0.1uF) around the board that implements this circuit, but I don't have any right next to the particular JK flip flop chip. I will try to jam one in there by hand to see if it makes a difference.

@Javaxtreme is it intentional that you used HCT logic family? The reason for the "T" is that they have TTL compatible inputs (but CMOS outputs). Since you are driving them with CMOS signals, using HC family would have better noise margin.

@Burglups I shoved a 100nF (0.1uF) capacitor into the circuit and it didn't fix the issue. The behavior noted in my original question doesn't happen all the time, but it's frequent. Adding the cap ?maybe? helped a bit, but the phenomenon definitely still occurred. As for the implementation, the board that implements the screenshotted schematic is a PCB and the clocks are also PCBs. There is a little bit of breadboard setup at the moment to measure things. I have a couple clocks I've tried. 555 timer-based, OCXO oscillator, and a CMOS oscillator (S7D1.843200A20F30T).

@ThePhoton that's a very astute question. This circuit is part of a much larger cpu I designed and built from scratch. There are around a hundred chips in total, and some of them started out as LS-variety ones. I have been moving to HCT over time, but haven't been able to completely phase out the TTL level ones, so that's why this circuit uses HCT logic. Are you thinking this issue is due to noise? If so, I would love to learn about how noise could masquerade as a positive clock edge!

@Javaxtreme, if noise (or interference or distortion) causes a bump in the wrong place on a falling edge, it could be mistaken for a rising edge. This is also why so many people are asking whether you have adequately decoupled/bypassed your power supplies.

Commonly there is a 100nF (ceramic) capacitor for each digital IC. A single one for a hundred chips is not enough. And a 1 to 10 µF polarized (tantal) capacitor for each ten ICs is also quite common. -- How did you build the device? Wire-wrapped, PCB, hand-soldered wires, breadboard?

@jAVAEXTREME  Please add this extremely important information to your question: "The behavior noted in my original question doesn't happen all the time, but it's frequent." || Also added comment redecoupling would help BUT please do ensure that edits do not change the actual original question.

@ThePhoton that makes sense. I'm not sure I entirely understand how the bumps manifest as a trigger event, but that may be for another day.

Thank you all for the responses. I tore everything down and did a lot of testing with the scope. What I discovered is there was significant (~1V) ringing/overshoot/undershoot coming from the oscillator itself! I set up a small breadboard with my oscillator and my clock generator, added a potentiometer, and discovered that with a series resistor around 800Ω the ringing subsided without much degradation in the rise/fall times. I think I've discovered the root of the problem. I don't fully understand how one would derive the resistor value, but for now I believe this is the solution.

@RussellMcMahon great point. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Consider adding a say 0.1 uF cap AT the /set pin. A major supply glitch might affect set operation.

With the help of the commenters I believe we discovered the problem.
The primary issue was coming from ringing in the clock input signal to the JK flip flop.
Even at the clock's oscillator output I saw notable ringing, overshoot, and undershoot in the ~1V range. Those large swings seem to have been enough to falsely trigger the JK flip flop, i.e. the clock input to the flip flop saw some of those swings as positive edges.
For posterity, the solution to all of this appears to be to include a "series termination resistor" or "source termination resistor".

The resistor R_s in the image above (Reference PDF) is the resistor. I setup a breadboard circuit and found experimentally that a value around 800Ω worked to smooth out the signal:

The top (cyan) line is coming from the oscillator directly and the bottom (yellow) line is from the oscillator output through ~800Ω.
It's not clear to me how to prevent this issue without magical resistors with experimentally-derived values, so if anyone responds in the comments with a better solution, I will update this answer. For now, this solution is working well enough for me to proceed.
